# Jquery evento final do video

Tags: jquery, html, html5, vídeo

Bom dia, Estou com um problema, queria exibir um modal ao final de cada vídeo, no primeiro vídeo funcionou certinho, porém no segundo não estou conseguindo...

Segue código abaixo...

Se alguém puder ajudar agradeço muito!

```js
var vid = document.getElementById("video_ctrl"); 
    function playVid() { 
    myVideo.play(); 
    }
    document.getElementById('video_ctrl').addEventListener('ended',myHandler,false);
    function myHandler(e) {
     $('#myModal').modal('show');
    }
      
    document.getElementById('video_ctrl1').addEventListener('ended',myHandler,false);
    function myHandler(e) {
     $('#myModal1').modal('show');
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div id="div_video">
            <video autoplay id="video_ctrl" width="100%">
                <source src="img/abertura.ogv" type="video/mp4" />
            </video>
        </div>

            <script>
                function setvideo(src) {
                    document.getElementById('div_video').innerHTML = '<video autoplay id="video_ctrl1" style="width: 100%;"><source         src="' + src + '" type="video/mp4"></video>';

                }
            </script>
      
        <div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
          <div class="modal-dialog">

            <!-- Modal content-->
            <div class="modal-content">
              <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                 <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-body">
                <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" onClick="setvideo('img/video2.mp4');" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
              </div>
            </div>

          </div>
        </div>
        <div id="myModal1" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
          <div class="modal-dialog">

            <!-- Modal content-->
            <div class="modal-content">
              <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                 <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-body">
                <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" onClick="setvideo('img/video2.mp4');" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
              </div>
            </div>

          </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isso acontece porque estas a criar o elemento dinamicamente, nesses caso é necessário <s>utilizar o observador de eventos [`on` do jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/on/) e</s> adicionar o evento função após a criação do elemento:

```js
$('#myModal').on('hide.bs.modal', function setvideo(event) {

    var src = $(this).data('next-video');
    
    $('#div_video').html('<h5>Vídeo 2</h5><video id="video_ctrl1" style="width: 100%;" autoplay><source src="' + src + '" type="video/mp4"></video>');
   
    $('#video_ctrl1').on('ended', function(e) {
        $('#myModal1').modal('show');
    }); 
});

$('#video_ctrl').on('ended', function (e) {
    $('#myModal').modal('show');
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div id="div_video">
    <h5>Vídeo 1</h5>
    <video id="video_ctrl" width="100%" autoplay>
        <source src="http://www.w3schools.com/tags/movie.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
    </video>
</div>

<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog" data-next-video="http://www.w3schools.com/tags/movie.mp4">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        
        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        
    </div>
</div>
<div id="myModal1" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        
        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        
    </div>
</div>
```

**Obs.:** Eu utilizei o [evento `hide` do modal Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-events) para criar o vídeo e o parâmetro adicionei ao modal como um `data-attribute`, mas se quiser pode manter do jeito que estava utilizando. O ponto é registrar o evento após a criação do elemento.

Comment: Não deu certo, Agora não abriu o modal nem do primeiro video :(

Comment: Opa @YuriRodrigues, por algum motivo ele não funcionou como deveria, mas não estou com tempo pra investigar agora. Editei a resposta, dessa forma com certeza funciona.

Comment: Muito obrigado, deu certo! Salvou meu dia!.